# Create a relationship by ID using Neo4J and Spring Data

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have defined a simple node object like this:

```
@Node("product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String sku;

    ...

    @Relationship(type = "SOLD_BY")
    private Set<Shop> shops = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

However, my concerns are:

- To create (and save) a new `Product` I must not only create the `Product`, but also the list of `Shop` objects. And maybe a `Shop` object holds an `Address` object or a list of `Employees` itself. This means I'm forced to construct a huge list of objects.
- Also, maybe the `Shop` objects are already existing in the database and I don't want to overwrite them by saving the new `Product`.
- By loading a `Product`, all related `Shop` objects will be loaded and so on. But I'm just interested in the `Product`, not in everything connected to it.

So instead I want to do this:

```
    @Relationship(type = "SOLD_BY")
    private Set<String> shops = new HashSet<>(); // Just the IDs of the Shops
```

- Is this possible?
- Is this a valid approach to solve my problem?